# How to do realtime face detection?

Tags: iphone, opencv, camera, face-detection

how can I realize realtime face detection, when I use iPhone camera to take picture?

just like the example: http://www.morethantechnical.com/2009/08/09/near-realtime-face-detection-on-the-iphone-w-opencv-port-wcodevideo/ (this example don't provide the .xcodeproj, so I can't compile .cpp file)

another example: http://blog.beetlebugsoftware.com/post/104154581/face-detection-iphone-source
(can't be compiled)

do you have any solution? please give a hand!

Answer (score 2):

Wait for [iOS 5](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios5/):

> Create amazing effects in your camera
>   and image editing apps with Core
>   Image. Core Image is a
>   hardware-accelerated framework that
>   provides an easy way to enhance photos
>   and videos. Core Image provides
>   several built-in filters, such as
>   color effects, distortions and
>   transitions. It also includes advanced
>   features such as auto enhance, red-eye
>   reduction and facial recognition.